# Split depending on space amount

Tags: php, regex

(Every * equals 1 Space, since I dont know how to keep all the spaces and not get formatted into 1)

I have an output looking like this:

```
Austria Wien*****Rapid Wien
FC Admira Wacker*SCR Altach
RB Salzburg******SKN St. Pölten
WolfsbergerAC****SV Ried
SV Mattersbur****Sturm Graz
```

I would like to be able to split each row into 2 teamnames. If I split with

```
preg_split("/(  +)/", $input_line);
```

It almost works with the exception of the 2. line (FC Admira Wacker SCR Altach) since the space between the Team names is just 1 too and it then doesn't split at all. Can anyone can help me out with this please?

---

> [image]

> [image]

I made 2 screenshots from where I read the source code from, the first one is the original table, the second one (not filtered yet in the picture) shall only include the names of both teams as an output (The scores are already handled)

Maybe this helpes to come up with alternatives.

Comment: try `preg_split("/(  *)/", $input_line);`
**Edit** that wont work cuz there is alot of spaces between every word

Comment: I would say that it isn't possible, since it doesn't seem to be any pattern to how many spaces there are. Looking at the second row, for example. It would be impossible to know which space to split it on.

Comment: Perhaps looking at the data at the original source might help find a better solution because if you were to split on single space you would get very odd results. Where does the data initially come from and how do you get it?

Comment: hmm, those spaces between the teams names based on what?

Comment: What's the source of the content?

Comment: im using phantomjs to read the source code of a webpage, and the spaces between the teamnames are preformatted just like i did it in the example.

Comment: i can offer a solution if the teams names are fixed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i am understanding correctly, I don't think its possible to do what you want with a preg split. Give the number of spaces between the names can vary from as low as 1 & space chars are valid within the names.

Making a wild assumption on your data source though - I suspect your column sizes are likely all fixed - ie. the space's are just padding, so that the second column is in the right place. In that case, I'd say just work out the size for each column, then grab each name using a substr of the correct char positions & trim em to get your final value.

Hope that helps (it quite possible it may not, without the real data its impossible to tell, sorry)

Comment: I'll add some additional info to your answer if you are fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if the team names were split by more than one space, in which case you could use a simple regular expression:

`/ {2,}/`

Which would match 2 or more spaces.